# The GitLab pipeline is not executing the command in the script section for a docker image

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run the below job/stage in .gitlab-ci.yml

```
contract-tagging:
  image: pactfoundation/pact-cli:latest
  stage: contract-tag
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - broker create-version-tag --pacticipant service-name --version $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA --tag production --broker-base-url http://localhost:9090
```

The pipeline is not executing the 'broker' command in the script section. However the stage is completing with successful status.
I see the below message in the log

```
Running before_script and script
00:01
 Could not find command "sh".
Running after_script
00:02
 Could not find command "sh".
```

Below is the complete log.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.0.2 (772163a2)
   on csl-runner GwZBZUWZ
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:08
 Using Docker executor with image pactfoundation/pact-cli:latest ...
 Pulling docker image pactfoundation/pact-cli:latest ...
 Using docker image sha256:d4188166dd9c3a1652ce9c63759f194f410322c6e9709df1c15efd07eba4297c for pactfoundation/pact-cli:latest ...
Preparing environment
00:02
 Running on runner-gwzbzuwz-project-7336-concurrent-0 via runner-gwzbzuwz-gitlab-nonprod-runner-agent-1599663074-8439e49e...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
 $ git config --global http.sslVerify false; git config --global http.proxy http://proxy.local.xxxcloud.uk:yyyy; git config --global https.proxy http://proxy.local.xxxcloud.uk:yyyy;
 Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
 Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/repo-name/.git/
 From https://gitlab.nonprod.xxxcloud.uk/repo-name
  * [new ref]         refs/pipelines/xxxx -> refs/pipelines/xxxx
 Checking out bb9d023e as cdc-pact-poc...
 warning: unable to rmdir 'bash-scripts': Directory not empty
 Removing .m2/repository/
 Removing bash-scripts/
 Removing target/
 Updating/initializing submodules...
Restoring cache
00:04
 Checking cache for default-1...
 No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted.
 Successfully extracted cache
Downloading artifacts
00:01
 Downloading artifacts for compile (3768666)...
 Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=3768666 responseStatus=200 OK token=Z3G8Ws6y
Running before_script and script
00:01
 Could not find command "sh".
Running after_script
00:02
 Could not find command "sh".
Saving cache
00:01
 Creating cache default-1...
 .m2/repository/: found 5176 matching files
 Archive is up to date!
 Created cache
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:02
 Job succeeded
```

I could not find any solution on the web.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docker image you choose to run your ci-stage uses an entrypoint that doesn't allow to run scripts with CMD, as is expected for the [Docker executor from gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/12.10/runner/executors/docker.html#the-entrypoint).
You have to build your own image or you override the entrypoint in the .gitlab-ci.yml

```
contract-tagging:
  image:
    name: pactfoundation/pact-cli:latest
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I will try this one and update you.